# Difference between instance_eval and class << self?

Tags: ruby

I can't seem to grasp the exact difference between these two "constructs". To my mind, the following small script should output the same thing three times:

```
class Example
  puts self

  class << self
    puts self
  end

  instance_eval do
    puts self
  end
end
```

However, the output is:

```
Example
#<Class:Example>
Example
```

Here's my rationale:

- `Example` is an instance of `Class`, so `self` in the class body refers to that;
- `class << obj` sets `self` to whatever `obj` is in the given block, which in my case is the instance of `Class` that is `Example` (this is where I'm probably wrong);
- `instance_eval` runs the block in the given instance, so, in my case it's pretty much the same as putting the code in the block directly in the class body.

My current guess is that `class << self` inserts a ghost class between `Example` and `Class` and sets self to that, but the output of `#<Class:Example>` is not confirming that at all.

So what is wrong with my rationale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `class << obj` sets `self` to whatever `obj` is in the given block, which in my case is the instance of `Class` that is `Example` (this is where I'm probably wrong);

No, `class << obj` opens up the *singleton class* of `obj`. As you correctly pointed out, inside of a class declaration, `self` refers to the class itself, so, in this case, the "inner" `self` (i.e. the one being passed to `puts`) refers to the *singleton class* of `Example`.

Comment: Ah, so I was right (I call it the *ghost class*). It should have outputted something like `#<SingletonClass:Example>` or `Example*`, not `#<Class:Example>`. I think that's what confused me the most.

Comment: @Felix: Yeah, the `inspect` output for singleton classes isn't exactly obvious. By the way: now that `Object#singleton_class`, `Object#define_singleton_method` and `Object#singleton_methods` are in the core library, the naming debate seems to be settled, especially since the Final Draft of the ISO Ruby Specification also uses singleton class.

Comment: @Joerg: "now" being Ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: 1.9.0, I think.

Comment: örg This is the first time I have heard about an ISO Ruby Specification. Apparently it has been in the works since 2009. That is awesome news, thanks for bringing it!

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, `class << self` has been one of the most obnoxious bits of syntax in Ruby. People new to the language have little idea what it means, apart from cargo-cult conventions, and even those intimately familiar with the language have only a hazy understanding of what differentiates it from `instance_method`, as the two do seem to be remarkably similar.

Here's an example of two different ways of defining a class method:

```
class Example
  class << self
    def class_def
      :class_def
    end
  end

  instance_eval do
    def instance_def
      :instance_def
    end
  end
end
```

You can check that these work by calling the methods:

```
puts Example.class_def.inspect
# => :class_def
puts Example.instance_def.inspect
# => :instance_def
```

The difference is when you're dynamically creating methods using `define_method` since the binding does appear to be incorrect on the `instance_eval` version:

```
class Example
  class << self
    define_method(:class_def) do
      :class_def
    end
  end

  instance_eval do
    define_method(:instance_def) do
      :instance_def
    end
  end
end
```

This results in the `instance_def` method being defined, but not being bound to the class itself:

```
puts Example.class_def.inspect
# => :class_def
puts Example.instance_def.inspect
# => NoMethodError: undefined method ‘instance_def’ for Example:Class
```

The only reliable way to create dynamic methods is with `class << self`. The method `instance_def` appears to be created and discarded as it doesn't show up in Example.methods even inside that block.

Comment: I hadn't though about that. Interesting. So complex than I imagined. Reading your answer, it looks like `def` is the odd one. It makes difference whether it is surrounded by `instance_eval` or not, that's the strange part.

Comment: +1, however, in your last example, `instance_def` is not discarded, but it is created as an instance method (because it would be the same as calling `define_method` in the class body). If you were to do `Example.new.instance_def` you'd get `:instance_def`.

Comment: Ah, so that's where it ends up. Didn't think to check there.